# Getting a parse error in the following code which says "expected '(' but got an identifier"

Tags: blockchain, solidity

pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract hadcoin_ico{

```
//introducing the total number of available tokens for sale
uint public max_hadcoins = 1000000;

//introducing usd to hadcoin connversion rate
uint public hadcoin_to_usd = 1000;

// introducing the number of coins that have been bought
uint public number_of_coins_sold = 0;

//mapping for investor to its equity in the hadcoin
mapping (address => uint) equity_in_hadcoin;
mapping(address => uint) equity_in_usd;
modifier can_buy_hadcoin(uint usd_invested){
    require(usd_invested*hadcoin_to_usd + number_of_coins_sold <= 1000000 );

}
function equity_in_hadcoin(address investor) external view returns (uint){
    return equity_in_hadcoin[investor];

}
function equity_in_usd(address investor) external view returns (uint){
    return equity_in_usd[investor];
    
**function buy(address investor, uint usd_invested)external**
can_buy_hadcoin(usd_invested){
    uint hadcoins_bought = usd_invested*hadcoin_to_usd;
    equity_in_hadcoin[investor] += hadcoins_bought;
    equity_in_usd[investor] = equity_in_hadcoin[investor]/1000;
    total_hadcoins_sold += number_of_coins_sold;
}
function sell_hadcoin(address investor, uint hadcoins_to_sell) external{
    equity_in_hadcoin[investor] -= hadcoins_to_sell;
    equity_in_usd[investor] = equity_in_hadcoin[investor]/1000;
    total_hadcoins_sold -= hadcoins_to_sell;
```

}

In the following code, the buy function in the 28th line is giving a parse error when compiled using solidity remix code

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could perhaps shorten the code a bit, and add a stacktrace/proper explanation of your proble, you're more likely to get an answer. While writing, there's a preview below the edit box. Use that and ensure it's neat.

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is that:

First, the can_buy_hadcoin modifier is missing the '_;' in its body.

Second, the equity_in_usd function is missing the '}' in its body.

Third, the function name 'equity_in_hadcoin' is the same as the mapping name, which will cause an error. To solve this, you can either change the function's name or the modifier's name.

Fourth, the function name 'equity_in_usd' is the same as the mapping name, which will cause an error. To solve this, you can either change the function's name or the modifier's name.

Sixth, 'total_hadcoins_sold' variable does not exist, so function 'buy' and function 'sell_hadcoin' will both result in an error. To avoid this, you just need to
declare and instantiate it globally.

And finally, seventh, you are missing the closing '}' for the contract.

Hope you find this information helpful :)